# Android Rectangle Issue

Tags: java, android

```
left = (int)event.getX();
top =(int)event.getY();
right = (int)event.getX();
bottom =(int)event.getY();
```

Logcat give the result as

> LOGCAT ==>(l, t, r, b) = (225, 181, 1509, 572)

---

while

```
Rect touchRect = new Rect(left, top, right, bottom);
```

Logcat give the result as

> LOGCAT ==> (touchRect) = Rect(225, 181 - 1509, 572)

Why there is no parameter separator between top and right? Instead it shows weird "-".

Comment: now... what is the issue? it is just a string... the developer of that class probably thought it was clean and clear

Comment: you can even read the code here: http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/5.1.1_r1/android/graphics/Rect.java#Rect.toString%28%29

Comment: `toString()`: http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/5.1.1_r1/android/graphics/Rect.java#Rect.toString%28%29

Answer (score 0):

Do you see implementation of rect toString method?

```
@Override
public String toString() {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(32);
    sb.append("Rect("); sb.append(left); sb.append(", ");
    sb.append(top); sb.append(" - "); sb.append(right);
    sb.append(", "); sb.append(bottom); sb.append(")");
    return sb.toString();
}
```

If you need other string you need extends Rect class and override this method